# Erro ao rodar aplicação Web em flask - Python

Tags: python, flask

Olá, estou tentando rodar essa aplicação em Flask e quando tento visualizar a página no navegador aparece erro de servidor, quando eu apago a linha do código que cria uma lista de itens em que cada item é um link para outra página o erro some, então tenho certeza que o erro está nessa parte do código:

```
<ol>
 {% for i in range | atividades %}
 <li>{{<a href="{{ url_for('link_atividades[i]')}}">{{atividades[i]}}</a>}}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Estou chamando o template dessa forma no arquivo python:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    atividades = ["Estudar","Programar", "Praticar Karate", "Trabalhar", "Hobbies"]
    link_atividades = ["estudar.html","programar.html" ,"praticar_karate.html" ,"trabalhar.html" ,"hobbies.html"]
    return render_template("index.html", atividades=atividades, link_atividades=link_atividades)
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Coloque ali na pergunta como você está chamando esta view também,

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, ja adicionei.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar algo como:

Em sua rota:

```
atividades = [
    {
        'atividade':"Estudar",
        'url':"estudar.html"
    },
    {
        'atividade':"Programar",
        'url':"programar.html"
    },
    {
        'atividade':"Particar Karate",
        'url':"praticar_karate.html"
    },
    {
        'atividade':"Trabalhar",
        'url':'trabalhar.html'
    },
    {
        'atividade':"Hobbies",
        'url':'hobbies.html'
    }
]
```

Em em seu template:

```
<select>
{% for atividade in atividades %}
     <li>{{<a href="{{ url_for('atividade.url')}}">{{atividade.atividade}}</a>}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```